# Analytic continuation of the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_6F_5$

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I was doing some calculation and the generalized hypergeometric function ${}_6F_5(\{a_i\},\{b_i\},1)$ popped up with parameters such that $\sum_i(b_i-a_i)<0$ which means the series expansion does not converge on the unit circle. Is there an analytic continuation of the above function? It would really help if you could point me to some resources. Thanks.

Comment: Analytical continuation from which domain? You have z=1. It's simply series of complex number. Isn't it? Could please explain if I misunderstood.